# Google Sheets split words then sort Alphabetically, Using arrayformula

Tags: sorting, join, google-sheets, array-formulas, alphabetical-sort

I have multiple rows, containing varying number of cells, and in each cell I have one or more words.

I'm looking for a way to go row by row:

- Splitting the multiple words into single word parts (with space (" ") as the delimiter)
- Sort the parts alphabetically
- Put the parts back into multiple word cells
- Remove duplicates in the row

Already the first, seemingly easy part, gave me issues. Even if I just tried to look at one row, the closest I got was the code below and that inserted strange " " for the one word cells, and also failed to sort

```
=iferror(arrayformula(transpose(sort(transpose(SPLIT(transpose(B3:3)," "))))),"")
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8w7C.png)

I also tried to cut, sort and join the above output using the Query Header trick, but it refuses so sort anything but the first row

```
=arrayformula(trim(transpose(query(SORT(transpose(B12:D)),,COLUMNS(B12:D)))))
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7GFD.png)

I haven't even attempted combining the two things together, considering my epic fails above.

The final input document will have lots more rows and columns, so I also need to make sure this works without any hard coding of row or column numbers.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

I might have something for you.  It's a little bit of an odd way to do it, but it could work I think.

[Take a look at this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czBJldIwe7Gx0x33ppBqm8IgksrjTuQgXElZKSKSjlA/edit?usp=sharing).

The original data is in the Original tab in cells B3:J, all the way down.

The Converter tab puts every thing in one column, then there is a "dragdown formula" that'd need to be dragged down a long ways depending on how big your data set it is.  The good news is that you can just do it for thousands of rows beforehad and it will remain blank.

the New Data tab has just one formula and will repopulate your data the way it was, but with the resorted words.

Try messing with the data on the Original Data tab as much as you want.  see if New Data reflects what you'd want.